# remove sphinx from custom folder

Tags: server, uninstall

i need remove sphinx app, installed in custom folder 
`/usr/local/sphinx/`

I have tried:
 `apt-get remove sphinxsearch`
but it not work. how i do that?

Answer (score 0):

The directory `/usr/local` is not used by apt or other system package managers.   That directory is for you, the sys admin, to use for installing packages without risk of colliding with the system package manager.  You will need to remove it manually, e.g. `sudo rm -r /usr/local/sphinxsearch`, as well as other files that may pertain to it...if you want it to be completely gone.

Do you recall how it got installed?  If it was from source (.e.g `./configure && make && make install`) you'll be able to used `make uninstall`.

Or, check for an `install.sh` script.  That would give you hints to other files that may have been installed.

Comment: yes, it was from source. in folder i have /bin, /etc, /share, /var sub folder.
install.sh not found